# Angular.js directive template using variable from parent/inherited scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, compilation, angularjs-directive

I want to chose directives templateUrl depending on some variable from its parent scope. I can't use templateUrl function, since it doesn't have a scope yet. I can $compile the template from $templateCache(note that it's already there, I'm not loading it) from inside the linking function, but I am afraid it's gonna have a negative impact on performance(let say this is a table cell directive.. and there's quite a few cells).

Do I have any other, better option?

Comment: I´m afraid not. I already had a similar requirment and couldnt find a better solution then using the `$compile`-Function. As for the performance: I´m not really sure if it decreases the performance that much - since Angular would do the same thing if you would provide it with a `templateUrl`-Property.

Comment: yeah, but if I'm not mistaken, it does it twice, once during it's own compile and then again when it's ready in link function.. which also means it start compiling when everything else is ready, so it has to be somewhat slow.. I think.. unless it doesn't compile when you don't provide template.. which would make sense I guess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is indeed no other way around. Although you should `$compile` this way to achieve somewhat satisfactory performance results.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/22646392/301596