# SEO for a single view AngularJS app

Tags: angularjs, seo

I have a SPA [here](http://goo.gl/eT0gpj) and I´m wondering what should I do to get it properly indexed by Google bot.

I read a lot on multiple views angularjs apps (hashbanging and that stuff) but my app has just one view / controller.

Should I create an html copy for each of the items being shown and link them together?

Thanks in advance,

Ariel

Comment: Have same problem. I think google still doesn't care about our SPA. I'm guesing the only way is to generate static pages for google ?_escape_fragment_ query. My SPA is empty for "fetch as google"

Answer (score 0):

In AngularJS, you can [compile templates & cache them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22639396/angular-js-caching-compiled-templates-rendering-performance-of-directives-ins/22646392#22646392) using a variety of techniques - you'll need to write a process or build into your runtime logic building these templates & binding them to data, writing them out as static files.

Google allows for [special handling based on user-agent](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/mobile-sites/mobile-seo/configurations/separate-urls?hl=sr#automatic-redirection).  I have a friend who says, "This was called cloaking, before Google owned Angular."  This is true.  You need to setup server logic that re-directs any `Google-bot` user agent (or other search engine agents you care about) dynamically to one of these static "Search-Bot Friendly" pages.

Although this is more work, there are obviously bonuses to being able to maintain a set of content that search crawlers "see" and a (potentially different) set of content consumed by real users.

This is also the reason why AngularJS as a client-side framework quickly falls down the rank list when search visibility is a primary objective of the project.

Comment: This is a great article that goes more in depth on "how-to". http://www.yearofmoo.com/2012/11/angularjs-and-seo.html